# Можно ли стандартными методами создать группу гостя в Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Мне необходимо, чтобы неавторизованные пользователи имели группу, скажем "Гость", настраиваемую также, как и все остальные группы. Можно ли стандартными методами Django сделать так, чтобы каждый неавторизованный пользователь числился в группе "Гость", и соответственно имел её права? Либо же придётся при каждом запросе проверки прав делать запрос на request.user.is_authenticated, и если он False, то вручную прописывать значение для группы?
Если это можно реализовать нормально, прошу объяснить, как.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно докам можно отдавать права через методы указанные в доках через бэкэнд аутентификации

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#authorization-for-anonymous-users

Сам список групп отдать не получится, но можно радавать права:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
class AnonBackend(BaseBackend):
    def get_group_permissions(self, user_obj, obj=None):
        if user_obj.is_is_anonymous:
            return Group.objects.get(name="анонгруппа").permissions.all()
        return super().get_group_permissions(user_obj, obj)
```

и добавь в  AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS